# How to remove spacing between bars in column chart SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I remove spacing between bars in SSRS 2012 report.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In design mode, select one of the columns in the chart.

In the Properties pane, look for CustomAttributes; expand that group.

Look for PointWidth within that property group. Change that value from 0.8 (the default) to 0.9 for the columns to be a little closer together. Change the value to 1 if you want your columns to touch. Adjust as desired.

They keep this one hidden, a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the PointWidth property of the chart series to 1 if you want no space between, you can adjust this value to adjust the amount of space, the higher the number, the less space between, default is 0.8.

To get to this, click on one of the columns in the chart and then hit F4 to display properties (assuming Visual Studio here, I don't use report builder).

Under Custom Attributes, you will find PointWidth, change this value to 1 or maybe .095 to get a very narrow gap.

[image: PointWidth shown in properties pane]