# Size of series in chart design using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, charts

This is the problem I want this to be seems good

[image]

How does one change the width of a series in chart design for my Report using Visual Studio 2010 Charts?

Comment: Try the answer here to do what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985359/how-to-remove-spacing-between-bars-in-column-chart-ssrs-2012

Comment: all i need to change the width of the bar itself not the margin between bars  like the above link describe.

Comment: Yes, and changing the PointWidth property will do that.

Comment: i tried this many times but it working in visual studio2010 but not in Ax 2012