# SSRS bar chart with multiple categories

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have built some quite ssrs charts, but is it possible to create below bar chart n SSRS.

![click on the link below to show the bar chart][1]

but when am creating this in ssrs , am getting report as below.

I am getting the report in ssrs as below, but not like the above one:

![][2]

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Can you please brief me how to achieve this, i was trying but this is coming like as below.

Comment: post your result then i can able to help you out

Comment: Added the report, find the link in above

Comment: Suggest me how the data should be like to get report like this in SSRS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985359/how-to-remove-spacing-between-bars-in-column-chart-ssrs-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the heading as they are in your first image, you will need to be clever with your dataset.

Personally I would probably take the approach of including dummy chart values to get your Category heading without a corresponding bar in the chart, such as:

```
Group          Order  Category       Value
31 to 60 Days  1      31 to 60 Days  0
31 to 60 Days  2      Today          14
31 to 60 Days  3      1 Month Ago    12
31 to 60 Days  4      2 Month Ago    44
Up to 30 Days  1      Up to 30 Days  0
Up to 30 Days  2      Today          11
Up to 30 Days  3      1 Month Ago    8
Up to 30 Days  4      2 Month Ago    21
```

From which you can:

- Group your Categories using the `Group` value
- Display each Category in its correct order by sorting on the `Order` column
- Actually display your chart values using the `Value` column, which will show nothing for your group headings

How you get your data into that format will depend on your data source, but should be fairly trivial if you are using a SQL source.

Comment: Thank you!! But with my dataset its complexity to get the category heading, am trying to do this. thank u for ur solution

Comment: @user3851739  You already have you headings judging by the chart in your question?  Why can you not just use the same logic you used there?

Comment: No worries @user3851739.  For the benefit of other users with the same issue, if this was the correct answer to your question, please mark it as such.