# How do I increase spacing between bars in column chart in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The column chart in ssrs looks very messy. How do I rectify it?
[image]

Comment: Have you gone through this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985359/how-to-remove-spacing-between-bars-in-column-chart-ssrs-2012

Comment: Yes, I have used the PointWidth property. Still, the chart looks messy with many values overlapping.

Comment: it depends on what you expect. there are a lot of columns there so unless you can make the chart larger I don't see how you can do anything other than rotate the data labels and use a smaller font size and get rid of the flyout lines.